# Failed to draw a rectangle in OpenGL without VAO

Tags: opengl-es, vbo, vao

I drew a rectangle with VAO successfully. Now I try to do it without VAO because I want to to the same in OpenGL ES 2.0 and VAO is only support in OpenGL ES 3.0. However, I couldn't make it works, what am I doing wrong? Your attention and help is very much appreciated.

My vertex Shader:

```
attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec3 color;
attribute vec2 texCoord;


varying vec3 ourColor;
varying vec2 TexCoord;


void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position,1.0f); // Add the xOffset to the x position of the vertex position
    ourColor = color;
    TexCoord= vec2(texCoord.x,1.0f-texCoord.y);
}
```

My fragment Shader:

```
varying vec3 ourColor;
varying vec2 TexCoord;



uniform sampler2D ourTexture1;
uniform sampler2D ourTexture2;
uniform float mixValue;

void main()
{
gl_FragColor = texture2D(ourTexture1 , TexCoord);
}
```

My vertex attribute and indices:

```
GLfloat recVertices[] = {
        // Positions          // Colors          // Texture Coords
        0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f,   // Top Right
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f,   // Bottom Right
       -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f,   // Bottom Left
       -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f    // Top Left 
    };

    GLuint indices[] = {  // Note that we start from 0!
        0, 1, 3, // First Triangle
        1, 2, 3  // Second Triangle
    };
```

My code with VAO works fine:

```
GLuint VBOs[2], VAO ;
glGenBuffers(2, VBOs);

glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);

glBindVertexArray(VAO);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOs[0]);//0. Copy verticles array for OpenGL to use
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(recVertices), recVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[1]);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// 1. set the vertex attributes pointers
// Position Attribute
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
// Color Attribute
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
//Texture Coordinate Attribute
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(6 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
//Unbind VBO
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);


glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

My Code without VAO, using VBO only doesn't work. It doesn't draw anything:

```
    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    GLuint VBOs[2], ; // Initialize an buffer to store all the verticles and transfer them to the GPU
glGenBuffers(2, VBOs);


    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[0]);//0. Copy verticles array for OpenGL to use
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(recVertices), recVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[1] );
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    // 1. set the vertex attributes pointers
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    // Position Attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);

    // Color Attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));

    //Texture Coordinate Attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(6 * sizeof(GLfloat)));


    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

Comment: The `glBindAttribLocation` calls are at the wrong place. They have to be called after the shaders have been compile and **before** it gets linked. Otherwise `glBindAttribLocation` doesn't have any effect.

Comment: @BDL So I should put them into the **linkProgram** function, after the `glCompileShader` and right before the `glAttachShader`, right?

Comment: Yes. But that might not be the problem since they most probably got the same locations assigned anyway. I just wanted to mention it.

Comment: So the `glBindAttribLocation` doesn't cause the problem at all and they has no proper use in my code ?

Comment: It might not cause the problem, but it should be there. There is no guarantee how attribute locations are assigned automatically but all implementations I know assign them automatic locations in the order they are defined in the shader code.

Comment: Thanks alot for your mention, It help me understand more about it. I still couldn't resolve my problem though. Hope someone could come across and help me out.

Comment: dont see glgenbuffers

Comment: It was there but I forgot the copy it into the code block. Sorry for the mistake.